# robots.txt URL format

Tags: robots.txt

According to [this page](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

> globbing and regular expression are not supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines

However, I noticed that the [stackoverflow robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) includes characters like * and ? in the URLs. Are these supported or not?

Also, does it make any difference whether a URL includes a trailing slash, or are these two equivalent?

```
Disallow: /privacy
Disallow: /privacy/
```

Comment: depends on the robot i guess

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second question, the two are not equivalent. `/privacy` will block anything that starts with `/privacy`, including something like `/privacy_xyzzy`. `/privacy/`, on the other hand, would not block that.

The original robots.txt did not support globbing or wildcards. However, many robots do. Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo agreed on a standard a few years back. See http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improving-on-robots-exclusion-protocol.html for details.

Most major robots that I know of support that "standard."