# Robots.txt disallow path with regular expression

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Does `robots.txt` accept regular expression ?
I have many `URL`s with this format:

```
https://example.com/view/99/title-sample-text
ID ----------------------^
Title -----------------------------^
```

I used this:

```
Disallow: /view
```

But look like this not working because `google` indexed more pages. so i want to do this with regex, something like this:

```
Disallow: /view/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)
```

But is this correct format or valid in `robots.txt` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde *Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on StackOverflow.*

Comment: This is programming!!

Comment: @Padideh no it's not. You're not writing code, you're writing a config file.

Comment: So what is programming about SEO?! @PaulTomblin anyway, where i should as this???

Comment: Well, you could do what I did and spend 3 seconds typing "how to write a robots.txt file" into Google.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I know how to write a robots.txt file! Agent, allow, disallow or etc.. the question is how to use regular exp in robots.txt

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538859/robots-txt-url-format) I found in the related section at least answers that it's possible.

Comment: @Padideh and if you'd done that google search I suggested, you would have seen that you can't do regular expressions, but Google and some of the other crawlers recognize `*` globs.

Comment: Config is code. It is machine-interpreted. It's just not Turing complete (in most cases).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a wildcard ...

```
User-agent: *
disallow: /view/*
```

See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72722/can-we-use-regex-in-robots-txt-file-to-block-urls

Hope this helps.